# Domain of x^(1/3)

Tags: functions

[image: Domain of x^(1/3)]

Why the domain is all non negative real numbers if the function exists from -inf to +inf as we can see clearly from the graph?

Comment: 1. If this is purely an Alpha question, this is off-topic here. 2. The plot is of the real and imaginary parts and not the function itself, if you look carefully.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The real part of the function is the blue one. And I can see that goes from -inf to +inf, so why the domain is "all non negative numbers" ?

Comment: It's saying that the cube root is *not real* if the argument is negative. (Note the heading above "Domain".) Otherwise, the plot of the imaginary part would have been flat all throughout.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to Mathematica.

Comment: The $1/3$-power function -- which is the *principal* cube root functions, that is, one of the three distinct complex-valued functions $f$ that satisfy the equation $f(x)^3  = x$ -- gives real values only for those real inputs $x$ satisfying $x \geq 0$. *Mathematica* distinguishes this from the "real-valued cube root function" `CubeRoot` that has domain $(-\infty, +\infty)$ and gives real values on that domain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says "Properties as a **Real** Function" above "Domain". So it's correct: the function's value for `x<0` is complex.